# How can I create a CSV file in a directory and store data from my loop in a proper format?

Tags: php, csv

I want to create a CSV file from my data. This is my loop:

```
foreach($animals as $row) {
    $row['species'];
    $row['name'];
    $row['size']
}
```

This is how I create my CSV. So far this works:

```
$country = 'africa';

$newFileName = './files/'.$country.".csv";
$newFileContent = 'here should be my content';                          

if(file_put_contents($newFileName,$newFileContent)!=false) {
    echo "File created (".basename($newFileName).")";
} else {
    echo "Cannot create file (".basename($newFileName).")";
}
```

But I have a problem to create from my loop in a proper CSV format.

With the help of a tutorial I tried this:

```
$country = 'africa';

$newFileName = './files/'.$country.".csv";
$newFileContent = $animals; 

foreach ($animals as $line) {
    fputcsv($newFileName,explode(',',$line));
}

if(file_put_contents($newFileName,$newFileContent)!=false) {
    echo "File created (".basename($newFileName).")";
} else {
    echo "Cannot create file (".basename($newFileName).")";
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your file for writing first and grab the file handle:

```
$country = 'africa';

$newFileName = "./files/" . $country . ".csv";

$fileHandle = fopen($newFileName,"w"); // Open file for writing

foreach ($animals as $line){
  fputcsv($fileHandle, explode(',',$line));
}

fclose($fileHandle);  // Make sure we close file after finishing writing to it
```

Comment: Hi, this works well (I updated one line like @mapek suggested), thank you! How can I check with your code, if the file was created or not? Because with your code my check is not working

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first `foreach` loop in your question `$animals` is an array containing arrays with keys `species`, `name` and `size`.

So you have to change

```
foreach ($animals as $line){
   fputcsv($newFileName,explode(',',$line));
}
```

to

```
foreach ($animals as $line){
    fputcsv($newFileName, array($line['species'], $line['name'], $line['size']));
}
```

because `$line` is already an array and should be exploded.

Comment: I put the three values in a separate array because there are maybe other fields in `$line` that shouldn't be exported to the CSV file.

Comment: I did like you said and my result in my CSV file is `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`

Comment: How does `$line` look like in the foreach loop? Please add `print_r($line);` and show me the output.

Comment: shell I write it print_r inside the loop?

Comment: This is the result: `Array ( [number] => 1234 [species] => monkey [name] => frank [size] => 120` and so on...

Comment: That looks okay. Have you already changed your code like @BaZ suggested in his answer? The combination of out answer should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95578/discussion-between-jarla-and-mapek).

Comment: I don't know which one of you I should mark as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've always done it in the past.

```
$country = 'africa';

$fileName = "./files/" . $country . ".csv";

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

$headerDisplayed = false;

foreach ( $animals as $line ) {
    // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        // Use the keys from $line as the titles
        fputcsv($fh, array_keys($line));

        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }

    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, $line);
}
// Close the file
fclose($fh);
// Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
exit;
```

Comment: Nice. You couldave yourself checking the if statement(assuming you know $animals is an array) everytime by `if(count ($animals > 0) fputcsv($fh,array_keys(reset($animals)));` before the foreach. +1 regardless

Comment: Ah yeah. I was just assuming it was an array. Good call.